# Copying UUID field from one document to the other discards BinData type - PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I insert a document in a collection, with one of the fields being an `uuid`:

```py
collection.insert_one({"_id":123, "someField": uuid.uuid4()}
```

Then, I want to fetch this document and copy its `someField` value to a new document in the same collection:

```py
oldDoc = collection.find_one({"_id": 123})

collection.insert_one({"_id":456, "someField": oldDoc['someField']})
```

For the first insertion I observe the document having stored the `someField` field as `BinData(3,2RHWV3bHRzum4ygmxLO3uA==)`.

On the second insertion, the `someField` is stored as `{hex: <hex_of_the_uuid>}`

How can I make sure to preserve the BinData type in the second document?

---

It is perhaps important to mention that this change in how a type is stored affects my `find` queries, because I store a `hex` representation of the `uuid` in the frontend and convert it to `uuid` when querying. I use `uuid.UUID(<hex_rep>)` to convert the value from the frontend, and I use `str(doc['someField'])` to get the hex representation for the frontend.

---

I've also tried reading the documentation of the `bson` module, and the [legacy caveats of UUID in Mongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/uuid.html), but I could not figure out a solution - I tried to manually handle the conversions but instead of a `BinData(3, 2RHWV3bHRzum4ygmxLO3uA==)` thing I get:

```
{ "py/newargs" : [ BinData(0,"2RHWV3bHRzum4ygmxLO3uA=="), 3 ], "_Binary__subtype" : 3 }
```

which also breaks the `find` queries.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and couldn't reproduce the issue. What versions of MongoDB and pymongo are you using?

```
import uuid
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db['collection']
collection.insert_one({"_id":123, "someField": uuid.uuid4()})

oldDoc = collection.find_one({"_id": 123})
collection.insert_one({"_id":456, "someField": oldDoc['someField']})

for record in collection.find({}):
    print(record)
```

prints:

```
{'_id': 123, 'someField': UUID('a878c87f-cc6d-4d84-857b-121e44b9847b')}
{'_id': 456, 'someField': UUID('a878c87f-cc6d-4d84-857b-121e44b9847b')}
```

Comment: The MongoDB version is `5.0.2`, and the pymongo version is `3.12.0`

Comment: Did you try the sample above and get the same results?

Comment: I have tried many similar cases; the main difference is that my `uuid.uuid4()` is never stored as UUID, but as BinData. In Mongo 5, it seems like if I want to store something as UUID, I should manually use this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/#convert-character-string-to-uuid

What version did you try this with?